# Xcode 5 scheduled Bot not integrating

Tags: xcode, cocoa, continuous-integration, bots

I've created a bot on my local server that will build periodically every day. When I do a manual integration (Integrate now) it works fine. Everything builds.

However, when the bot should build on a specific time it won't start integrating.

When I view the bot in the browser it gets stuck on: 
   **the bot has been queued and will integrate shortly**

and nothing happens. I've tried hourly and daily.

Even tried restarting the computer and server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering back and forth I now managed to fix the problem. It was the easiest solution ever. Just delete old bots and create new ones. I thought I did this, but maybe I didn't.

Anyway it now builds as it should.

Comment: I had the same problem, but the new bot still is queued and does not integrate.